# Get value of parent object base on value from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

From a json, Can I get the value base on a value of key from another object? How will I do that? using array filter or for loop?

I have tried using array filter but it only returns the whole json object

Here is my sample JSON:

```
[
  {
    "type":1,
    "key": "123abc",
    "data": {
        "access": "123456"
        "data": {
          "dataValue": [
            {
              "@attr": {
                 "@key": "Fire"
              },
              "@value": "Flame"
            },
            {
              "@attr": {
                 "@key": "Water"
              },
              "@value": "Liquid"
            },
            {
              "@attr": {
                 "@key": "Earth"
              },
              "@value": "Stone"
            }
          ]
        }
     }
  }
]
```

What I want is to get the "Liquid" value from @value by searching for "Water" from the "@key"

Output:
Liquid

Thanks you for those who will help.

Comment: Don't forget to also add your attempt for others to assist with.

Comment: sorry, next time i will put what my attempts here. I just don't have confidence yet to put my not working code :(

Comment: I will learn from this code. Im new in programing and doesn't know much yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filter as follows from the parsed object:

```js
let obj = [{
  "type": 1,
  "key": "123abc",
  "data": {
    "access": "123456",
    "data": {
      "dataValue": [{
          "@attr": {
            "@key": "Fire"
          },
          "@value": "Flame"
        },
        {
          "@attr": {
            "@key": "Water"
          },
          "@value": "Liquid"
        },
        {
          "@attr": {
            "@key": "Earth"
          },
          "@value": "Stone"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}];

console.log(obj[0].data.data.dataValue.filter(a => a["@attr"]["@key"] == "Water")[0]["@value"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to simplify this down a little bit and say that we're working on the `dataValue` array.

```js
    // For each item in dataValue, check the key.
    // If it equals 'Water', return the value.
    for (let i = 0; i < dataValue.length; i++) {
        if (value['@attr']['@key'] === 'Water') {
            return value['@value'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This will get the value of the object

```js
var json = JSON.parse(`[{"type":1,"key":"123abc","data":{"access":"123456","data":{"dataValue":[{"@attr":{"@key":"Fire"},"@value":"Flame"},{"@attr":{"@key":"Water"},"@value":"Liquid"},{"@attr":{"@key":"Earth"},"@value":"Stone"}]}}}]`);

function getValue(dataValues, key) {
  return dataValues.find(function(item) {
    return item["@attr"]["@key"] === key;
  });
}

var dataValues = json[0].data.data.dataValue;
var dataValue = getValue(dataValues, "Water");
console.log(dataValue["@value"]);
```

This will get you the value for each object

```js
var json = JSON.parse(`[{"type":1,"key":"123abc","data":{"access":"123456","data":{"dataValue":[{"@attr":{"@key":"Fire"},"@value":"Flame"},{"@attr":{"@key":"Water"},"@value":"Liquid"},{"@attr":{"@key":"Earth"},"@value":"Stone"}]}}}]`);

function getValue(dataValues, key) {
  return dataValues.find(function(item) {
    return item["@attr"]["@key"] === key;
  });
}

console.log(json.map(function(jsonObject) {
  return getValue(jsonObject.data.data.dataValue, "Water")["@value"];
}));
```

Comment: thank you. This works too, I will study this code and will use this in the future if needed. This helps me understand finding values in a nested json. Im new in programing and doesn't know much yet